# How to specify key and value with length in hadoop streaming?

Tags: hadoop, key-value, hadoop-streaming

In hadoop streaming, "-D stream.map.output.field.separator=. \"and "-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=4 \" is used to specify the key field and value field.
But in my question, there is no separator at all, records as follows:
AAA__BBBBBB        CCC__DDDDDD
I want to specify the 1 to 3 char as the key and last as value, how can I do?
Further more, where will be secondary key problem(for secondary sort), how to specify them?

Comment: What do you mean by secondary key? Hadoop will sort first by your keys and second by your values. If you set up your key/value pairs correctly then all of the sorting should happen correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like:

```
AAA__BBBBBB
CCC__DDDDDD
...
```

then you definitely have a separator. The `__` will be your separator and you can tell hadoop this with the following command:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-D stream.map.output.field.separator=__ \
...
```

Your keys would be `AAA` and `CCC` and your values would be `BBBBBB` and `DDDDDD`. You won't need `-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=4` because you only have one separator (`__`).